# MVVM application with background thread doesn't close

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, mvvm-light

I am using MVVM Light and in my view model I initialize a Phone object which has to continuously wait for new calls.

The thread is declared as follows:

`coreLoop = new Thread(LinphoneMainLoop);
coreLoop.IsBackground = false;
coreLoop.Start();`

When closing the main window, the application never closes.
I tried `ViewModel.Cleanup`, the destructor, and implementing `IDisposable`.
None of these methods worked, none got to the breakpoint.

I also wish to avoid handling the main window's close event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read the Remarks section of this [page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.isbackground%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

If the `Thread` object property `IsBackground` is not set to true, that means its a `Foreground` thread and application has to wait for it to finish to close the process. If it would be a `Background` thread, that means it would terminate the thread without waiting for it to complete.